# MyBatis : Using Multipe inputs from List<object> in Select statement for IN

Tags: mybatis

Passing List to MyBatis. can we pass multiple input to IN for SELECT statement as mentioned below. please correct me

```
dao interface:

public List<Integer> getObjects(List<Test> testList)


Mybatis :
<select id="getObjects" resultType = "Integer">
 SELECT KEY FROM TABLEA WHERE number IN(<foreach collection="TEST" 
  index="index" item="item" separator=", ">
  #{number}
</foreach>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code would work :

```
<select id="getObjects" resultType = "Integer">
 SELECT KEY FROM TABLEA WHERE number IN
 (<foreach collection="list" 
   index="index" item="item" separator=", ">
   #{item.number}
   </foreach>)
</select>
```